# Remove warnings instead of using backtrack option

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am not sure how to solve this problem without using backtrack=true;.

My sample grammar:

```
grammar Test;
options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
}

parse : expression 
      ;
expression : binaryExpression 
           | tupleExpression 
           ;

binaryExpression : addingExpression (('=='|'!='|'<='|'>='|'>'|'<') addingExpression)*
                 ;

addingExpression : multiplyingExpression (('+'|'-') multiplyingExpression)*
                 ;

multiplyingExpression : unaryExpression 
                        (('*'|'/'|'div'|'inter') unaryExpression)*
                      ;

unaryExpression: ('!'|'-')* primitiveElement;   

primitiveElement : literalExpression
                 | id
                 | sumExpression
                 | '(' expression ')'
                 ;  

sumExpression : 'sum'|'div'|'inter' expression
              ;

tupleExpression : ('<' expression '>' (',' '<' expression '>')*)
                ;

literalExpression : INT
                  ;              

id : IDENTIFIER
   ;

// L E X I C A L   R U L E S      

INT : DIGITS ;   

IDENTIFIER : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ;
fragment DIGITS: DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

Is there a way to fix the grammar such a way that no warnings can happen? Let's assume I want to choose both alternatives depending on the case.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

```
sumExpression : 'sum'|'div'|'inter' expression
              ;
```

gets interpreted as:

```
sumExpression : 'sum'   /* nothing */
              | 'div'   /* nothing */
              | 'inter' expression
              ;
```

since the `|` has a low precedence. You probably want:

```
sumExpression : ('sum'|'div'|'inter') expression
              ;
```

> Let's assume I want to choose both alternatives depending on the case.

That is not possible: you cannot let the parser choose both (or more) alternatives, it can only choose one.

I assume you know why the grammar is ambiguous? If not, here's why: the input `A div B` can be parsed in two ways:

### alternative 1

```
unaryExpression 'div' unaryExpression
      |                     |
      A                     B
```

### alternative 2

```
id sumExpression
 |       |   \
 A     'div'  B
```

It looks like you want `'sum'`, `'div'` and `'inter'` to be some sort of unary operator, in which case you could just merge them into your `unaryExpression` rule:

```
unaryExpression : '!' unaryExpression
                | '-' unaryExpression
                | 'sum' unaryExpression
                | 'div' unaryExpression
                | 'inter' unaryExpression
                | primitiveElement
                ; 

primitiveElement : literalExpression
                 | id
                 | '(' expression ')'
                 ;
```

That way you don't have any ambiguity. Note that `A div B` will now be parsed as a `multiplyingExpression` and `A div sum B` as:

```
multiplyingExpression
       /    \    
    'div'   unaryExpression
    /            / \ 
   A         'sum'  B
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I would like to actually allow ('div' expression) or (expression 'div' expression)? What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: @AndyM, err, did you try parsing `A div B` and only just `div B`? I'm pretty sure both are parsed just fine.